# Overriding BEM element modifier in SASS implementation

Tags: sass, bem

This has been puzzling me for some time.

We use Sass (SCSS) and implement BEM-like naming convention **over lib-sass**.

So, for example, we have:

```
.description {
  .title {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

and there can be `description--special` that wants to do the following:

```
.description {
  .title {
    color: red;
  }

  &--special {
    .title {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

naturally the problem of specificity arises, since the intended use is:

```
<div class="description description--special"></div>
```

Can someone suggest an elegant enough way of doing this?

The current "best" suggestion is to do this:

```
.description.description--special {
  .title {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

since, of course, in **lib-sass** at least, this doesn't work:

```
.description {
  .title {
    color: red;
  }

  &.&--special {
    .title {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

nor does this:

```
.description {
  &root: &;

  .title {
    color: red;
  }

  &.#{&root}--special {
    .title {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use BEM outside yandex.com. If you do not work in yandex - do not use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ampersand (&) at the end, and part of, a selector in SASS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501114/ampersand-at-the-end-and-part-of-a-selector-in-sass)

Comment: LibSass is not the same as Sass.  It is approximately 1-2 versions behind Sass, and the feature you're looking for is only available in the most recent version.

Comment: Note that if you respect BEM, your `.title` should be outside `.description` and be named `.description__title`.

Comment: @LeBen True, but this is exactly the reason we don't go full BEM. It's BEM + OOCSS over SMACSS-like structure. OOCSS part here is relevant because that `title` is a reusable pattern and can't be coded into the description (again, the naming here may not be the best).

Comment: @cimmanon sass development is paused specifically to get `lib-sass` up to speed.

Comment: @ZenMaster : OK, I'm going to edit my answer with the syntax I use to mix OOCSS and BEM.

Comment: @Pinal - can you elaborate? why not?

Comment: @ToniLeigh There's no reason to not use BEM outside of Yandex. Read this: http://www.sitepoint.com/working-bem-scale-advice-top-developers/

Answer (score 4):

## With a pure BEM syntax

HTML:

```
<div class="description description--special">
  <h1 class="description__title"></h1>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.description {
  &__title {
    color: red;
  }

  &--special &__title {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

## With an alternative BEM syntax and OOCSS

Here is the alternative syntax I use:

- ComponentName
- ComponentName.modifierName
- ComponentName-descendantName
- ComponentName-descendantName.modifierName
- ComponentName.isStateOfComponent
- nonBemPrefix-something (for example "ob-myCssObject")

The following code is close to yours. HTML:

```
<div class="Description special">
  <h1 class="ob-title"></h1>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.ob-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Description {
  .ob-title {
    color: red;
  }
  &.special {
    .ob-title {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

As a third proposition, I suggest not to pollute your BEM rules with OOCSS. HTML:

```
<div class="Description special">
  <h1 class="Description-title ob-title"></h1>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.ob-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Description {
  &-title {
    color: red;
  }
  &.special &-title {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

NB: You should consider to stay in the BEM way, with a component `Title` instead of a CSS object `ob-title`.

Comment: This is definitely the answer.

Comment: What if I want to do this without having an element? Looking at your first example, I want the color to be on the block (`description`) and I want to add a modifier **to the block** that changes the color?

Comment: @Botis Then it is a modifier, like `.description--special`.