# Assign element selector as combinated selector through the given class in SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have following case:

```
.description {
  // styles
}
```

and I want to assign an element selector on before with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). That the output would be:

```
label.description { /* styles */ };
```

is it somehow possible to do this within the class:

```
.description {
  label&
}
```

similar to a `&` combinator but to put it before the class. Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible....but intrigued to find out if it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to place the `&` after in order to reference parents, they have it in [their documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector):

```
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
  body.firefox & { font-weight: normal; }
}
```

The last line:

```
body.firefox & { font-weight: normal; }
```

Is compiled to:

```
body.firefox a {font-weight: normal; }
```

The syntax you described (`label&`) produces this  error:

> Invalid CSS after "label": expected", was "&"
>
> "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.

**However**, there are 2 alternatives, one is creating another rule:

```
label {
  &.description {/*styles*/};
}
```

And the other, is very similar to the one you want, using [`@at-root`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) and [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) you can write:

```
.description {
  @at-root label#{&} {/*styles*/}
}
```

This will produce:

```
label.description {
  /*styles*/
}
```

This was based [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507304/1326147).

Comment: A very unfortunate limitation, as type selectors cannot appear anywhere but the beginning of a compound selector, thus creating a conflict with Sass's `&`. The reason `&` can appear at the end in your `body.firefox &` example is because it appears at the end of a *complex* selector, but as its own compound selector, separated from the `body.firefox` compound selector by a descendant combinator.

Comment: @Armfoot In the future, refrain from answering duplicate questions (seriously, this question is asked at least once every other week).  Your answer was wrong when this question was closed.  It's not appropriate to copy answers from one question to another.

Comment: @cimmanon I have only found the other question when someone referred there was a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501114/ampersand-at-the-end-and-part-of-a-selector-in-sass/)... I updated my answer and linked [your answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22507304/1326147). But, if you notice, it's not exactly the same question, while they both use & after compound selectors, this question is asking for an HTML tag selector, while the other is asking for classes selectors (despite working in the same way). I also tested his syntax and provided documentation links.