# Switch icons on the :after parent element using & when the class is different

Tags: sass

I am trying to target the parent box element to change the icon in :after Pseudo element. When I place the ampersand after the class it steps out to: .box-example-default #pageContainer .box .box-header Is this not how your supposed to use it? Any suggestions

```
<div id="pageContainer">
    <div class="box box-example box-example-default">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Title<h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box box-example box-example-simple">
        <div class="header">
           <h1><h1>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
.box {
    .header{
        &:after{
         position: absolute;
         right:0;
         bottom:-63%;
          content: '\f0ce';
         display:block;
         font-family: "FontAwesome";

         .box-example-simple &{
              content: '\f0ce';
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand at the end will not work for you because you need `.box` and `.box-example-simple` at the same level. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501114/ampersand-at-the-end-and-part-of-a-selector-in-sass)

You can use `@at-root` and `#{&}` to achieve this, like so:

```
.box {
    .header{
        &:after{
         position: absolute;
         right:0;
         bottom:-63%;
         content: '\f0ce';
         display:block;
         font-family: "FontAwesome";

        @at-root .box-example-simple#{&} {
              content: '\f0ce';
           }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it might be cleaner to just write it out the long way:

```
.box {
  .header {
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
      bottom:-63%;
      content: '\f0ce';
      display:block;
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
    }
  }

  &.box-example-simple {
    .header {
      &:after {
        content: '\f0ce';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the first example did not do the trick it still creates output to: .box-example-default #pageContainer .box .box-header:after. I do agree that the second example is cleaner (which is what I have been using).

Comment: Strange, if you look [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/95c549ea6d515b5dd053e434aeb7dd99) it does compile to `.box-example-simple.box .header:after`. The `#{$}` syntax is only valid in Sass 3.4 though. Either way, glad you got it working!